# In Python 3.8.2, how do I convert a string that contains a '\uxxxx' sequence into utf-8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I have a Python string that contains the following: `it\u2019s`. When I print the string, it shows as `it\\u2019s`. The `\u2019` represents the unicode RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, here serving as an apostrophe in "it's".

I want to change the `\u2019` into the actual unicode character, but I'm stymied. I *have* found that I can do it using `str.replace("\\\u2019", "\u2019")`, but there are several metric tons (tonnes?) of unicode characters and I'd like a more general solution.

Additional information:
I'm using Windows 10, and using the python interpreter for testing. I hope this will help.

```
>>>s = "it\\u2019s"  # that is two backslashes is a row.
>>>print(s)
it\u2019s
>>>b = s.encode()
>>>print(b)
b'it\\u2019s'
h = b.hex(" ",1)
>>> print(h)
69 74 5c 75 32 30 31 39 73
```

So there is a 5c in the hex; that's a backslash. The backslash is actually part of the string, not python interpreting a unicode escape sequence.

Comment: It's your terminal not being able to print unicode characters. May I know what terminal you are using? In Windows CMD it's printing properly.

Comment: Please see the additional information I added to the question.

Comment: How did you end up with this string? Would it not be possible / make sense to not escape the `\uxxxx` sequence then? Or you have no control over how the `str` happens to be and really must convert afterwards?

Comment: I'm using the Python csv module to read an Excel spreadsheet saved as csv file. The "pretty" apostrophe is there in the Excel file, but apparently Excel writes csv files in 7-bit ascii -- as a UTF-8 with BOM. It boggles the mind.

Comment: Not sure how this will show up in the comments:with open(file2, newline="") as csvfile2 :
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile2)
    rows2 = [row for row in reader2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimally I would suggest you try to make sure the `\` in your input is not escaped in the first place, but should that not be possible a regex substitution could do (`s` being your original string):

```
re.sub(r"\\u([0-9a-f]{4})", lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), s)
```

Find occurrences of `\\u` followed by four lowercase hex digits and group them in the first group for back reference. Replace these sequences with character corresponding to he int value represented by those four digits: `chr(int(m.group(1), 16)`

Comment: np, still, I'd try to look for a way how to read the input "correctly". ;)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the backslash, the u, and the four digits are all utf-8 characters in the csv file. I'll dig more into the csv module to see if I'm missing something.